# Is an extension of a constant function in a interval necessarily constant?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f(z)$ be an analytic function and let $g(z,\theta)=f(z)$ for $\theta$ real. Suppose that for $z \in \Omega \subset \mathcal{C},$ $g(z,\theta)$ with $\theta \in \mathcal{C}$ is an extension in $\theta$ of $g(z,\theta)=f(z)$.

Is the extension $g(z,\theta)$  in $\theta$  of  $g(z,\theta)=f(z)$ necessarily and equal to $f(z)$ for $z \in \Omega \subset \mathcal{C}$?

Comment: What do you mean by "extension"? Does $g(z,\theta) = f(z)+\mathop{\rm Im}\theta$ qualify?

Comment: I will update my question to make it more clear